# How to change label data value using jquery

Tags: jquery, label

I have a label like this, I just want to change the data value using jquery, I tried below code but it's not working, any suggestions appreciated

```
<label id="lblFilingFee" name="lblFilingFee" data-filingfee="50.00"> $ 0.00</label>

$(trLineItem).find("#lblFilingFee").data("filingfee").val('0.00');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax to add/update value of data is .data( key, value )

```
$(trLineItem).find("#lblFilingFee").data("filingfee",'0.00');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery `attr` to achieve this

```
$(trLineItem).find("#lblFilingFee").attr("data-filingfee", '0.00');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#lblFilingFee").attr("data-filingfee", '0.00');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lblFilingFee" name="lblFilingFee" data-filingfee="50.00"> $ 0.00</label>
```